# To this riddle, I invite

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is to ride
>   My infix is to write
>   My suffix is to go inside

What am I? Answer it right! 

**A brief guide:**
No, the answer does not rhyme with the clues supplied.

Comment: Just noticed that even invite, right, guide, and supplied rhymes with the riddle! :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are a,

> carpenter.

The prefix is,

> car, which is to ride.

The infix is,

> pen, which is to write.

The suffix is,

> enter, which is to go inside.